# Como rastrear coordenadas do mouse em uma QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt, eventos-do-mouse, qtgui, gui

Olá, estou com um projeto com telas utilizando o Qt Creator e estou preso com o seguinte problema: Quero rastrear as coordenadas do mouse ao mover o cursor em cima de uma QLabel. Vi em alguns outros tópicos alguns casos resolvidos, porém sempre haviam de criar uma Classe manualmente para o QLabel, como utilizei o editor do Qt creator entao ficou mais dificil de se alterar a classe QLabel. Eis abaixo o método que ativaria o rastreamento do mouse na tela.

```
void mainwindow::on_ButtonAddFileira_clicked(){

    this->pTimer.disconnect();
    QImage image;

    image.load("C:/Users/Syn/Desktop/TCC/Fotos Bolsão FEI/02 Bolsao_Cheio_Foreground.jpg");

    //image = MatToQImage(this->ImagemBase.capturaImgBuffer());
    ui->labelScreen->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    ui->labelScreen->setScaledContents(true);

    ui->labelScreen->setMouseTracking(true);

}
```

A idéia é que ao clicar em um botão, o rastreio do mouse seja ativado e eu possa identificar suas coordenadas x,y na imagem da qLabel. Abaixo um método que talvez possa ajudar, mas nao estou sabendo como utilizá-lo:

```
bool mainwindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){

if (qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj)== ui->labelScreen && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
  {
    QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    qDebug() << QString("Mouse move (%1,%2)").arg(mouseEvent->pos().x()).arg(mouseEvent->pos().y());

    ui->label_X->setText(QString().arg(mouseEvent->pos().x()));
    ui->label_Y->setText(QString().arg(mouseEvent->pos().y()));

  }

  return false;
}
```

Alguém saberia como posso fazer isso com a QLabel fixa gerada pelo editor, ou seja, sem criar uma classe separada para a Label? Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível recuperar a posição global do cursor na tela utilizando o método estático [`QCursor::pos()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#pos), como você quer obter a posição dentro da label você pode utilizar o método [`QWidget::mapFromGlobal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal).

```
QPoint cursorPos = ui->label->mapFromGlobal( QCursor::pos() );
```

Se as coordenadas x ou y forem negativas ou estiverem ultrapassando a altura ou largura da label quer dizer que o mouse está posicionado fora da imagem.

Pela sua pergunta também entendi que você precisa manter a informação atualizada constantemente após um determinado evento. Como você citou que não é viável estender a classe `QLabel` creio que a solução seja utilizar um `QTimer` com um intervalo curto (e.g. 100 ms, 50 ms) e recuperar a informação sempre após esse intervalo.

```
void mainwindow::on_ButtonAddFileira_clicked(){
    // carrega imagem
    QTimer *cursorTimer = new QTimer;
    connect(cursorTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(cursor_timer_timeout()));
    cursorTimer->start(100);
}
```

Obs.: O código acima é um exemplo, lembre-se de liberar o timer quando ele não for mais necessário.

Outra solução possível é utilizar a função `promote` do editor do Qt Creator, ainda é necessário estender a classe `QLabel` mas dessa maneira o Qt Creator pode entender a mudança que foi feita e se ajustar corretamente. Comece criando uma classe que herde de `QLabel`.

```
class MyImageLabel : public QLabel
{
    // ...
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
};
```

Agora basta abrir sua janela no editor clicar com o botão direito na label e clicar em `Promote to...`, preencha o campo `Promoted class name` com o nome da sua classe e clique em `Add`, selecione ela da lista acima e clique em `Promote`. Agora basta sobrescrever o método `QLabel::mouseMoveEvent()` na sua nova classe, algo como:

```
void MyImageLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << e->pos();
    return QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(e);
}
```

Dessa maneira a posição do mouse pode ser recuperada em tempo real utilizando o método [`QMouseEvent::pos()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent).

Leia mais em [Using Custom Widgets with Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela respota, mas agora após criar a classe acima e chamar o metodo 'QmouseEvent::pos()', eu recebo 2 mensagens de erro, são elas: _no matching function for call to 'MyImageLabel::MyImageLabel(QWidget*&)' myImage = new MyImageLabel(mainwindow);_    e a outra é _cannot call member function 'QPoint QMouseEvent::pos() const' without object _ saberia o que esteja causando este erro?

Comment: Verifique se você declarou corretamente o construtor da classe, ele deve receber um ponteiro para `QWidget` e chamar o construtor da classe pai repassando esse ponteiro. Você pode também criar a classe pelo Qt Creator, indo em `File` -> `New File or Project` -> `C++` -> `C++ Class`. Use `QLabel` no campo `Base class` e `QWidget` no campo `Type information`.

Comment: Valew amigo, tentei do primeiro jeito com o QTimer e funcionou, pelo método da subclasse eu tentei mas meu compilador insiste em acusar erro no construtor, embora eu creio ter declarado tudo corretamente. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.